# JXLS Losing rows when using if-command inside each-command

Tags: java, excel, jxls

**Used versions**
poi :3.15
jxls : 2.4.0
jxls-poi : 1.0.12

Here is a [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8wEJ.png) allowing a simple reproduction of the problem.
Please note that I'm using the multisheet feature of JXLS.

When the *if-condition* is true (the site has an address) the result is displayed as expected
but when it's false and no adress is displayed I lose 2 rows, number 7 and 8, replaced by blanks rows.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v19ve.png)

**As anyone already encoutered such problem ?
Am I making a mistake in the way I'm using JXLS to create my sheet ?**

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String first = "Bob";
    String last = "John";
    String phone = "";
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1 ; i<10 ; i++) {
        personList.add(new Person(first + i, last + i, phone + i));
    }

    List<Site> mySites = new ArrayList<>();
    Site site = new Site("site 1", "Paris", "", "rue 1", "rue 2", personList);
    mySites.add(site);
    site = new Site("site 2", "", "Bob", "", "", personList);
    mySites.add(site);

    ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream template = null;
    if (contextClassLoader != null) {
        template = contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("test1.xls");
    }

    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:/temp/res.xls"));

    org.jxls.common.Context contextData = PoiTransformer.createInitialContext();

    Map<String, Object> beansData = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> sheetNames = Arrays.asList("site1","site2");
    beansData.put("mySites", mySites);
    beansData.put("sheetNames", sheetNames);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : beansData.entrySet())
    {
        contextData.putVar(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    JxlsHelper.getInstance().setUseFastFormulaProcessor(false).processTemplate(template, os, contextData);

    template.close();
    os.flush();
    os.close();


}
```

}

Regards,

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: It looks like a bug. Please raise an issue in Jxls issue tracker

Answer (score 1):

The issue is now fixed and the fix will go in the next Jxls release v2.4.1.

See [issue#77 JXLS Losing rows when using if-command inside each-command](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/77/jxls-losing-rows-when-using-if-command) for more detail.